# Unbind Backbone View Events

Tags: javascript, events, backbone.js, coffeescript

I have the falling events hash -

```
events:
  'click #someButton : 'someFunction'
```

To close the view I have tried

```
close:
  $("#someButton").unbind("click")
```

and

```
   `close:

       $("#someButton").remove()`
```

But someFunction is still being fired more than once. How do I unbind this event from the button?

I've also tried

```
$(@el).find("#someButton").unbind("click") as well
```

Comment: always refer [Backbone Documentation](http://backbonejs.org/#Events)

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Backbone.js view events are delegated to the view's `el` (so there is no event bound to your `#someButton` element but rather when a click event bubbles up to the `el` it checks to see if the event came from an element matching that selector), that being the case to remove the event you need to remove it from the `el`, for example

```
  $(this.el).off('click', '#someButton');
```

If you want to remove all delegated events you can just use the view's [undelegate](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/#View-undelegateEvents) method

Comment: mhmm, I tried doing that, but the function is still firing more than once

Comment: Try something like `$(this.$el).off("click", "#someButton");`

Comment: it worked :) what was wrong with the unbind.click("click") thing?

Comment: A Delegated event is bound to some parent level element (in this case the view's `el`) and when an event bubbles up it checks to see if that event matches the selector specified. The event is not bound to the actual selector (in fact one of the common uses of event delegation is to bind an event for an element that will be added dynamically. You might want to read up a little more about it on the jquery docs for the [.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/) method

Comment: thanks, I was getting crazy, my events were firing multiple times 1x each render() call...

Comment: @Vland Your welcome. Depending on your setup you might want to consider using the [events hash](http://backbonejs.org/#View-delegateEvents) instead of binding them in your render.

Comment: Hi @Jack, is there a way we can attach an event to an element this way?  Like  $(this.el).bind('click', '#someButton');
Or for an instance, if I have removed an event like this, then what is the way to add that event back to the element?

Comment: @CodeKaro I'm not exactly sure what your asking but you can definitely bind directly to your root el without using the events hash and remove those same events. Just use a reference to your event handler, for example `this.$el.on('click', '#someButton', referenceToEvent)` and to remove `this.$el.off('click', '#someButton', referenceToEvent)`. To add back you would just use the .on method again. Just a note as of jQuery 1.7 [.on](http://api.jquery.com/on/) is the preferred way to attach event handlers instead of [.bind](http://api.jquery.com/bind/)

Answer (score 0):

Jack's explanation and answer are great. Unfortunately, his code example didn't work for me. Instead of using:

```
 $(this.el).off('click', '#someButton');
```

I had to use:

```
 this.$el.off('click', '#someButton');
```

which makes sense to me, because the event was bound to `this.$el` object.

Answer (score 0):

To add further, I used `this.$el.off();` inside an initialize within a subview to destroy all events tied to the subview. The same event would fire X number of times a data refresh was called.

I saw the duplicated targets using:

```
var $target = $(e.currentTarget);
console.log($target);
```

I would add a comment to an answer, but I have low reputation.