# unbind events when switching Backbone Views

Tags: backbone.js, view, infinite-scroll

I have a List view and a Detail view.

In list view, I have set up the jquery infinite-scroll plugin.

When a user clicks an item, I render the detail view. The problem is when the user hits bottom of the page, the infinite-scroll callback is fired.

I tried calling $.infinitescroll('pause') but it won't stop the fetch.

Should I completetly destroy the list view before rendering the detail view?
If so, how can I completely destory it? (I tried https://stackoverflow.com/a/11534056/433570 but didn't stop the infinite-scroll callback)

My code resembles https://github.com/joshbohde/django-backbone-example in a big picture

Comment: You should look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12359604/unbind-backbone-view-events

Comment: Yes, destroy the view when you're done with it. No need for a new method, just override [`remove`](http://backbonejs.org/#View-remove) to include your infinite scroll unbinding and chain to the base `remove`.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried doing event.stopPropagation on the scroll event inside the Detail view?